# How to re-execute failed scenario in Serenity-Thucydides?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jbehave, thucydides, serenity-bdd

I have set of feature files (say f1.feature,f2.feature..) each having certain number of scenarios (summing up to around 250).
While executing the test suite, if I see 100 scenarios in failed status; I want them to re execute.

Currently I am able to update properties file (having set of feature file names to be executed ) which can be fed to junit runner. But I want to pass property file (having scenarios list ) while executing maven command so that I would be able to execute only failed scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_retrying_failed_tests

> junit.retry.tests to true and max.retries to the number of times you
>   want failed tests to be retried. If max.retries provided and
>   junit.retry.tests=true, all method tests will be executed until first
>   successful run, but not more than 1 + max.retries times.

Comment: I'm using maven to execute tests and it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

@selva, I suppose this feature has been removed from serenity now. Please refer below link
https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-exercises/issues/1
we can use maven surefire plug in instead